# Printing key with multiple value php

Tags: php

I have created a hash with keys that have multiple value's and not sure how to print them to get my desired output. My hash is as follows:

```
 Array
 (
[developmental stage] => Array
    (
        [0] => dummy development1
        [1] => dummy development
    )

[treatment] => Array
    (
        [0] => dummy treatment1
        [1] => dummy treatment
    )

[age] => Array
    (
        [0] => dummy age
    )

 )
The expected output:

 developmental stage  treatment        Age
 dummy development1   dummy treatment1  dummy age
 dummy development    dummy treatment
```

Code to create the hash:

```
  $attribute[$property->type_id->name][]=$property->value;
```

Code that I have tried is as below. How do I get it to print as stated above?

```
     foreach ($attribute as $key=>$value) {
         echo "$keys\t";
         foreach($key=>$value as $key1){
             echo "$key1\n";
         }
       echo "\n";
     }
```

Comment: "This only prints the keys" well that's because you ONLY echo $key

Comment: Edited the code, should have been specific.

Comment: `foreach($key => $value as...` is incorrect, you want to `foreach($value as $value1)` - `$key1` is technically fine but is misleading in its naming convention, it's a value you're getting there not a key

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this:

```
function printArray($array = array()) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            printArray($value)
        } else {
            echo $key.'=>'.$value."\n";
        }
    }
}
printArray($yourArray);
```